# how can i return this Datatables funcion into globale function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

i want to create a global function that return data table in global JS file that i call in many html file into the project so I create this function

```js
function createDataTable(divname,data,sylangage,column){
    if (sylangage ==1) {
    var language ={
        "sEmptyTable":     "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
        "sInfo":           "Affichage de l'élément _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_ éléments",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Affichage de l'élément 0 à 0 sur 0 élément",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtré à partir de _MAX_ éléments au total)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Afficher _MENU_ éléments",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement...",
        "sProcessing":     "Traitement...",
        "sSearch":         "Rechercher :",
        "sZeroRecords":    "Aucun élément correspondant trouvé",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Premier",
            "sLast":     "Dernier",
            "sNext":     "Suivant",
            "sPrevious": "Précédent"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
            "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
        },
        "select": {
                "rows": {
                    "_": "%d lignes sélectionnées",
                    "0": "Aucune ligne sélectionnée",
                    "1": "1 ligne sélectionnée"
                } 
        }
    }}else 
    var language ={
        "sEmptyTable":     "No data available in table",
        "sInfo":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Show _MENU_ entries",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
        "sProcessing":     "Processing...",
        "sSearch":         "Search:",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "First",
            "sLast":     "Last",
            "sNext":     "Next",
            "sPrevious": "Previous"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
            "sSortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
        }
    }
    }
    
    var table = $(divname).dataTable( {
      
       
       data : data,
       "columns": columns,
       "oLanguage": language ,
       
       
      
    } );
    return table;
    }
```

And I call it into the HTML file so it shows this error in the console "get Illegal return statement "so I need to know if can draw the Datatable using this global function and correct the error.

```js
var divname = "#example";
var sylangage = 1;
function createDataTable(divname, data, sylangage, columns) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
function createDataTable(divname, data, sylangage, column) {
  let language;
  if (sylangage == 1) {
    language = {
      "sEmptyTable": "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
      "sInfo": "Affichage de l'élément _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_ éléments",
      "sInfoEmpty": "Affichage de l'élément 0 à 0 sur 0 élément",
      "sInfoFiltered": "(filtré à partir de _MAX_ éléments au total)",
      "sInfoPostFix": "",
      "sInfoThousands": ",",
      "sLengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ éléments",
      "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement...",
      "sProcessing": "Traitement...",
      "sSearch": "Rechercher :",
      "sZeroRecords": "Aucun élément correspondant trouvé",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "Premier",
        "sLast": "Dernier",
        "sNext": "Suivant",
        "sPrevious": "Précédent"
      },
      "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
        "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
      },
      "select": {
        "rows": {
          "_": "%d lignes sélectionnées",
          "0": "Aucune ligne sélectionnée",
          "1": "1 ligne sélectionnée"
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    language = {
      "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
      "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
      "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
      "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
      "sInfoPostFix": "",
      "sInfoThousands": ",",
      "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
      "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
      "sProcessing": "Processing...",
      "sSearch": "Search:",
      "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "First",
        "sLast": "Last",
        "sNext": "Next",
        "sPrevious": "Previous"
      },
      "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
        "sSortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
      }
    }
  }

  var table = $(divname).dataTable({
    data: data,
    "columns": columns,
    "oLanguage": language,

  });
  return table;
}
```

And then, you'd call this as:

```
// I assume data and columns are defined above
var divname='#example';
var sylangage=1;
let myTable = createDataTable(divname,data,sylangage,columns);
```

Comment: Thanks it show no more error that mean the code work perfect but the data table doesnt show in my page should i add something else to draw it thank you.